# Adding Values of Two Data.frame Objects into a New Data.frame

Tags: r, database, dataframe, aggregate

Can I ask for the right command in [R] to add the values in two data.frame objects to produce a third "aggregate" data.frame? Here's the data from [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/21896/67822):

```
Mercy Hospital
Type         A    B      C    D      E    All
Operations  359  1836   299   2086  149  4729
Successful  292  1449   179   434   13   2366
```

and...

```
Hope Hospital 
Type          A   B  C   D   E   All
Operations   88 514 222 86  45   955
Successful   70 391 113 12  2    588
```

The way I am doing is long and cumbersome:

```
 rbind(Hope[1,] + Mercy[1,], Hope[2,] + Mercy[2,])

                 A    B   C    D   E  All
    Operations 447 2350 521 2172 194 5684
    Successful 362 1840 292  446  15 2954
```

Comment: Why not just `Mercy[-1] + Hope[-1]`?

Comment: Or `Mercy[2:7] <- Mercy[2:7] +Hope [2:7]`

Answer (score -1):

Here is a way to do it with reshaping

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

list(hope = Hope, mercy = Mercy) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "hospital") %>%
  gather(variable, value, -hospital, -Type) %>%
  group_by(Type, variable) %>%
  summarize(value = sum(value)) %>%
  spread(variable, value)
```

Comment: What if the columns were in a different order? Or what if one had more letters than the other?

Comment: Just `Mercy + Hope[names(Mercy)]` ?

Comment: I see what you're saying. But I think this way is more flexible. It allows as many hospitals as you want, with as many or few common variables in whatever order.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Here's what I was looking for, circumventing the "Type" issue that I hadn't perceived initially:: `data <- cbind(Type=Mercy[,1], Mercy[-1] + Hope[-1])`. And, yes, *now* I am building on your tip in your comment on the OP.

Comment: @AntoniParellada Yes. Obviously you'll need to add that column, I haven't write as is just too obvious. Also, what you mean by "*now*"? So you are saying that there is a substantial difference between `Mercy + Hope` and `Mercy[-1] + Hope[-1]` ? Or between `Mercy[-1] + Hope[-1]` and `cbind(Type=Mercy[,1], Mercy[-1] + Hope[-1])`? It's *exactly* the same thing with some small cosmetics. If we would think your way, we would never close a single questions as a duplicate, because it's never the *exact* thing. The idea is that the comment solves your problem, and without it you wouldn't solve it.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Please believe me when I say that there was never anything untoward, at least not on purpose. I come to SO as a guest because I don't have background in coding (very far from it), and appreciate the help from people of your caliber. I had been trying with `+` and the `Type` got in the way. Your `Hope[-1]` suggestion was key to getting what I needed. So thank you.